# Bash: play all audio in the current directory

Tags: bash, audio, mime

Here's a bash script, it

1. gets all files in the current dir, then
2. gets all audio files among them (allowing file-names to have whitespace)
3. sends the list to the `audacious -p` - which should play the list.

The thirt step is where the script fails. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find $1 -name '* *' | while read filename; do

Type=`file -i "$filename" -F "::" | sed 's/.*:: //' | sed 's/\/.*$//'`

if [ $Type=audio ]; then
    List="$List '$filename'"
fi
done

audacious2 -p $List &
```

So the question is: how do i convert

```
file name 1
file name 2
file name 3
```

to

```
'file name 1' 'file name 2' 'file name 3'
```

in bash?

Comment: You'll want to watch out for *"Argument list too long"* errors on you `audacious2 -p ...` command, which will happen when you try to load lots of files. You might be better off using `audacious2 -E $filename` to append the file to the current playlist, or look into creating a temporary playlist from your list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
#find "$1" -name '* *' |  # Edited as per OP's request
find . -type f -name '* *' |
while read -r filename; do
    case `file -i "$filename" -F "::"` in
        *::" audio"/*) echo "$filename" | tr '\012' '\000' ;;
    esac
done |
xargs -0 audacious2 -p &
```

The main point here is to use `xargs` to feed a list of file names to a command, but I hope you will also appreciate how the pattern matching conditional is now a lot more elegant; definitely learn to use `case`. (I hope I got the output from `file` correct.)

**Edit** Updated to use `find -type f`, `read -r`, `tr '\012' '\000'`, `xargs -0`.  By using a zero byte as a terminator, whitespace and newlines in file names are acceptable to `xargs`.

Comment: It doesn't work (at least for me). The first line is actually should be `find "`pwd`" -type f |`. Thanks for the `case` trick.

Comment: Just `find .` should work then, unless you have other parts of the script which require absolute paths. Which part doesn't work for you?

Comment: The last line - the xargs one - doesn't work. Because my files has spaces. If I comment `| xargs audacious2 -p &` thing - the script echoes all right. But when uncommented xargs gets it all wrong.

Comment: Spaces where? Does it help if you use `read -r`? `xargs` copes well with spaces, but if you have newlines in file names, that could be a problem.

Comment: Oops, looks like BSD `xargs` will break on space, too.  Updated the script to use zero terminator and `read -r`.  If you are on BSD, adding single quotes in the `echo` would also work.

Comment: If it works better than "Bash FAQ #50", any chance you could accept this answer instead, or another one?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[BASH FAQ entry #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it with

```
#!/bin/bash
# enques all audio files in the dir and its child dirs to audacious.

# the following finds all audio files in the dir (and its child dirs)
find "`pwd`" -type f | while read filename; do
    Type=`file -i "$filename" -F "::" | sed 's/.*:: //' | sed 's/\/.*$//'`
    if [ $Type=audio ]; then
        # this enqueues them to audacious
        audacious2 -e "$filename" &
    fi
done

# and this line presses "play"
audacious2 -p &
```

It works fine.

**Edit**:

The problem also is solved in an "original" way (i.e. to put all songs as arguments to player, like that: `audacious2 -p "song 1" "song 2"`). Thanks to Ignacio for links, now it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
# enques all audio files in the dir and its child dirs to audacious.

# the following finds all audio files in the dir (and its child dirs)
find "`pwd`" -type f | {
while read filename; do
    Type=`file -i "$filename" -F "::" | sed 's/.*:: //' | sed 's/\/.*$//'`
    if [ $Type=audio ]; then
        List="$List \"$filename\""
    fi
done
echo $List | xargs audacious2 -p &
}
```

@tripleee:

It can be working in Your way without xargs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# enques all audio files in the dir and its child dirs to audacious.

find . |
while read filename; do
    case `file -i "$filename" -F "::"` in
        *::" audio"/*) audacious2 -e "$filename" & ;; # echo "$filename";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: [BASH FAQ entry #24: "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)